# Is the name `lib.rs` mandatory when creating a library with cargo?

Tags: rust

If I create a new cargo "package" with `cargo new --lib testlib` I can see that the resulting directory structure contains a `src/lib.rs` file.

I am aware that cargo uses the name `lib.rs` as a special name with special meaning. In other words, if it sees something called `lib.rs` it knows that it should compile the containing source code into a single binary library. This binary library is then available to be linked with other binary executables.

Is it possible to change the name `lib.rs` to something else, perhaps by configuring Cargo via the `Cargo.toml` file, or otherwise?

Essentially, I would really rather call the library root something like `kafkalib.rs`. I am not sure if this is possible.

One alternative workaround which occurred to me would be to declare a module within `lib.rs`.

```
mod kafkalib;
```

And then either create `./kafkalib/mod.rs` or `kafkalib.rs`, and put the associated Kafka library code in this file.

Then, helper code which is not directly related could either be placed in `lib.rs` directly, or in some other module adjacent to `kafkalib`.

Perhaps this "workaround" is actually the intended use? Since this is all still new to me I can't be sure what the most sensible approach is. The above is really a guess.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target

Comment: It seems completely unnecessary though, what does `kafkalib/src/kafkalib.rs` as crate root give you that `kafkalib/src/lib.rs` does not, for removing a consistent entry point?

Answer (score 2):

OOH, I get it I do: I write Typescript for a living and it's **extremely annoying** (especially when using `find` or it's fuzzy descendants) to have every other file be named `index.ts`.

OTOH, conventions exist usually for good reason and I would stick with lib/mod/main.rs where appropriate. If I (or anyone else, including you 6 months from now) have to troubleshoot a problem with your crate it's just easier to tell at a glance where the entry point is without having to open up Cargo.toml. Just sayin.

But if you can't resist, as Stargateur [links in the comments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/cargo-targets.html#configuring-a-target) you can set the `[lib]` section of `Cargo.toml` just like with `[[bin]]` to configure the target.

```
[lib]
name = "whatever"
path = "src/kafkalib.rs"
```